# What tools, or techniques are available for managing large sets of rewrite rules for Apache?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

We currently have a little over 450 rewrite rules in our Apache config spanning 4 different files. As you can imagine, they are vital to the way our site operates.

We of course test all the rules we add, have them in git, and ensure that they maintain the correct ordering so as to not step on each other's toes, but with a growing set of rules due to full-time development of the product, it's likely that this number will only increase.

What tools, and/or techniques do you use to maintain this vital (and potentially dangerous) configuration? What safeguards do you have to ensure that an improperly designed rewrite rule doesn't accidentally take out large portions of your site?

Comment: First, consider asking your question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), there are Apache admins there who will probably have better answers. Now, from a programming standpoint, I'd go with an exhaustive web test suite (including penetration tests for *potentially dangerous* URIs). All commits would be pushed to a staging server for testing, and only commits that pass all tests would be allowed to go further.

Comment: That's a good point about asking on serverfault--I hadn't thought about it, as I've never asked anything there.

Answer (score 0):

As we are facing the problem, we researched for ways to maintain large rulesets. In fact, there is no real tool for that. But there might be some ways to help you reduce / maintain your RWRs.

- Try using a coherent URL scheme, that can be translated to program logic. With this, you can use Routing Controller like the one of [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)
- You might be able to condense a set of rules by using [Apache's RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).
- Use TestNG and [Xenus Link Sleuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu%27s_Link_Sleuth) on your test stages to find out whether your rules still work. Therefore, every rule has to have it's own test.
- Debug your rules with the [apache rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).
- Knock on wood.